# Can't view the page after I uploaded on the webserver

Tags: php, passwords, webserver, password-hash, php-password-hash

This is working well on my localhost, but when I uploaded it on my webserver, it started giving me an error. It's not error actually but it's showing me a `page is not working. Page is currently unable to handle this request.` It's showing on my changepassword.php page. I'm not really sure what should I do?

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username='$user_check'");
$db_check=$db->query($sql);
if(password_verify($old_pwd,$db_check->fetch_assoc()['password'])){
    ...     
}
else{
    $error = "Old password is incorrect.";
    }
```

I tried

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username='$user_check'");
$db_check=$db->query($sql);
$row = $db_check;
if(password_verify($old_pwd,$row['password'])){
    ....    
}
```

but it's giving me a fatal error of

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array
```

Comment: Check your php version. password_verify is available only in v >= 5.5

Comment: Here you can follow http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: I already did and it's version 5.5.30, I included this lib from [this site](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) in my login page so that my `password_verify() function` will work, and it worked, I did the same on my `changepassword.php` but it's not working. @BikashPaul

Answer (score 1):

You can use fetch_assoc() for fetching the row.

Try the following code:

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username='$user_check'");
$db_check=$db->query($sql);
$row = $db_check->fetch_assoc();
if(password_verify($old_pwd,$row['password'])){
   ....    
 }
```

Comment: i just did, sorry, i didn't see your answer, but i did the same lol good job btw :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it. First, if you have a PHP version less than 5.5 and you are using a password_hash() in hashing your password, you have included [this libary](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) so that your `password_hash` function will work.

The reason why I can't view my changepassword.php page is because I used a wrong statement in my condition. So I did it this way instead and it's working now.

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username='$user_check'");
$db_check=$db->query($sql);
$row = $db_check->fetch_assoc();
    if(password_verify($old_pwd, $row['password'])){
        ...
    }
```